# "this" is different when function called from local function object

Tags: javascript, prototype, this

I wrote the following code, where I would expect the calls to getFull() and useGetFull() to do the same thing, since useGetFull just gets a function object for getFull() and calls it.

```
function Person(name, family) {
    this.name = name;
    this.family = family;
}

Person.prototype.getFull = function() {
    console.log(this.name + " " + this.family);
};

Person.prototype.useGetFull = function() {
    const f = this.getFull;
    f();
    // f.call(this) works as expected
}

p = new Person("Bob", "Smith");
p.getFull();
p.useGetFull();
```

However, they don't do the same thing, because inside useGetFull(), "this" is the global object. I noticed that using f.call(this) instead of f() works as intended, but I can't wrap my head around why I have to use it. Why is the value of "this" different depending on how/where I call the function?

Comment: I always avoid using 'this' in javascript when I can because I know pitfalls like this happen. :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Comment: Inside of 'useGetFull' you can also try this: `const f = this.getFull.bind(this);`

Answer (score 1):

A simple rule:

```
a.b() //b called with context a
d.e() //e called with context d
c() // c called with no context ( so the global instead)
```

Javascripts context depends on how the function was called.

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't noticed, `this.getFull()` also works. This is because when you invoke the function as a property of an object (any object), that function's `this` will refer to that object, the object you invoked the function on, in case of `foo.bar()`, `foo`, and in case of `this.getFull()`, `this`. This is why this example works as expected:

```
function Person(name, family) {
    this.name = name;
    this.family = family;
}

Person.prototype.getFull = function() {
    console.log(this.name + " " + this.family);
};

Person.prototype.useGetFull = function() {
    /* getFull is preceded by something, it is invoked through "this", so 
    the "this" reference inside of getFull will be set to the "this" part in 
    the statement "this.getFull()". */
    this.getFull();
}

p = new Person("Bob", "Smith");
p.getFull(); prints out Bob Smith
p.useGetFull(); // prints out Bob Smith
```

However, when a function is invoked not as the property on an object, in other words, when it is not accessed in a way similar to either `foo.bar()` or `foo["bar"]()`, but in a way like `foo()`, even if `foo` is a reference to a variable whose value is `x.y`, like `f()` in your example,  its `this` will be bound to the global object, in a browser, that object is `window`.

```
function Person(name, family) {
    this.name = name;
    this.family = family;
}

Person.prototype.getFull = function() {
    console.log(this.name + " " + this.family);
};

Person.prototype.useGetFull = function() {
    const f = this.getFull;
    /* this call is not preceded by any objects, it is a plain 
       traditional function call, it is a function invokation in its 
       simplest form. all functions invoked in this manner will have 
       their "this" reference set to the global object. */
    f();
}

p = new Person("Bob", "Smith");
p.getFull();
p.useGetFull();
```

If you are interested in `this` (pun not intended), go [here](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes/ch2.md).